# The title of the action sheet disappear form the view?

Tags: iphone, uiactionsheet

When button numbers of action sheet are more than 7, the title disappear from the view? How can i show it in the current view?

Answer (score 2):

Quite frankly, if you are presenting more than 7 buttons in an action sheet, you need to rethink the layout of that sheet.  You need to present the user with a more limited set of choices.  Having 7 options onscreen at once will lead to user paralysis by facing them with too many choices.

Comment: But the requirement is so. Why i think to use action sheet is that there is a default tableview in it. So if the buttons can show by scrolling the tableview.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a `UITableViewController` subclass which shows all the options instead of using a UIActionSheet in this case. You can put the title text into a section header or in the `tableHeaderView`.

Comment: That's maybe a solution. But the effect maybe not good.It can not show perfectly as action sheet.

Comment: But what the action sheet is presenting is a UITableView! You'll need to add some graphics to overlay it and add a cancel button with graphics on the bottom, but it's the same. Granted, you'll need to involve a graphic designer to make the graphics, but still, you probably should have a UI designer look at the overall design of the app.